# Need YouTube Videos to be loaded in a separate HTML page

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have loaded Playlist items in my Home Page like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="youtube-playlist-feed_1"></div>
<div id="youtube-playlist-feed_2"></div>
<div id="youtube-playlist-feed_3"></div>
```

My Script to load Playlist is:

```
            var htmlString = "";
            var apiKey = 'AIzaSyDI4rWo_wVAxRZEIgF6_8sRZDj8OCOZZ38';
            var playlistID = 'PLBhKKjnUR0XBVrHvtDOylN5XREHh9X1nt';
            var maxResults = 7;

            var playlists = [{
                playlistId: 'PLJYHm_ZxWCKnQmapkDs7x47jkr-nw3l50',
                el: '#youtube-playlist-feed_1'
              },
              {
                playlistId: 'PLJYHm_ZxWCKmIBkoopKFK4kTTOmC1Zof0',
                el: '#youtube-playlist-feed_2'
              },
              {
                playlistId: 'PLBhKKjnUR0XAM2Wvi7JY5gLRpFLzIE-An',
                el: '#youtube-playlist-feed_3'
              }
            ];

            playlists.forEach(function(playlist) {
              getVideoFeedByPlaylistId(playlist.playlistId, playlist.el);
            })

            function getVideoFeedByPlaylistId(playlistId, el) {
              $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=' + apiKey + '&playlistId=' + playlistId + '&part=snippet&maxResults=' + (maxResults > 50 ? 50 : maxResults), function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                  var videoID = item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
                  var title = item['snippet']['title'];
                  var videoURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoID + '&list=' + playlistID + '&index=1';
                  htmlString += '<div class="video-wrap"><div class="video"><a target="_blank" href="' + videoURL + '"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + videoID + '/mqdefault.jpg"></a></div>' + '<div class="title"><a target="_blank" href="' + videoURL + '">' + title + '</a></div></div>';
                });
                $(el).html(htmlString);

                htmlString = '';
              });
            }
```

Now, I have a separate page i.e. Player.html where I would like to have a YouTube Player and load the videos. For example, if a user clicks on 1st item of the playlist, that should be loaded in Player.html where I have my YouTube Player. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean [include html page in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)?

Comment: No, I have video links loaded in Home Page. Now, the scenario is that: when user clicks on 1st video, it should be played in YouTube Player which is on player.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your script where you are loading playlist items replace this code just **htmlString**

```
 htmlString += '<div class="video-wrap"><div class="video"><a target="_blank" href="#" onclick="player()"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + videoID + '/mqdefault.jpg"></a></div>' + '<div class="title"><a target="_blank" href="#" onclick="player()">' + title + '</a></div></div><input type="text" name="videoid" id="videoid" value="'+videoID+'" hidden>';
```

At the end of **Index.html** file:

Past this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function player() {

        var ID = document.getElementById('videoid').value;

  document.location.href = 'player.html?vid='+ID;

}
</script>
```

And in your `player.html` file

```
<div id="display"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
     var videoId = data.vid;
     var output = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'"></iframe>';
     document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all pass `VideoID` in `a href` by writing this as `a href`

```
    <div class="video-wrap"><div class="video">
<a target="_blank" href="player.php?id=' + videoID+ '">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + videoID + '/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
</div>' + '<div class="title"><a target="_blank" href="player.php?id=' + videoID+ '">' + title + '</a></div></div>
```

Now in `Player.php`

Use `GET` method to get your id variable
like : `$id = $_GET['id'];`
in this file use this code to play video

​`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $id; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

**In Your Videos displaying html file**
you have to write something like this:

```
<a onclick="player()" >Watch</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function player() {

         videoid = 'a9Vh9TZkdSM'; //Your Video id

  document.location.href = 'player.html?vid='+videoid;

}
</script>
```

And in

`Player.html`

Something like this:

```
<div id="display"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
     var videoId = data.vid;
     var output = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>';
     document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
```